# Angular controller in coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm trying to define an angular controller in my CoffeeScript file.

```
angular.module("myApp").controller('DashboardReportsController', ['$http', ($http) ->
  dctrl = @
  dctrl.setupDashboard = (id)->
    dctrl.business_id = id
    setBreakdownChart()
    return null

  dctrl.setBreakdownChart = ()->
    $http.get("/businesses/" + dctrl.business_id + "/dashboard/breakdown/").success( (data) ->
      exrevctx = document.getElementById("expenseRevenueChart")
      new Chart(exrevctx, data)
    )
    return null

  return this # Coffeescript auto returns the last line. Angular controllers are constructors so we must return `this`
])
```

I'm calling `ng-init` here:

```
<div class="row dashboard-grid" ng-controller="DashboardReportsController as dctrl" ng-init="dctrl.setupDashboard('<%= @business.slug %>')" >
```

I'm getting the error:

```
ReferenceError: setBreakdownChart is not defined
```

Between the error and breakpoints, I know `setupDashbaord` is being called but why is `setBreakdownChart` not defined?

Comment: In your setupDashboard() method you are calling setBreakdownChart(), yet you are not injecting that method.

Comment: Hey @Martin I'm still kinda new to Angular, but this is how I've written my controllers in the past and it has worked. Could you show me a code example on how to inject and fix this?

Comment: @martin nevermind I see it! Missing `dctrl.setBreakdownChart`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to reference the controller.  Change it to

```
dctrl.setBreakdownChart()
```

rather than

```
setBreakdownChart()
```